# Iframe div to be responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have 2 `div`. One with fixed left side `div` and another `div` has `iframe` in which websites to be loaded.

I want that `iframe` `div` to be responsive. I mean, I want all website contents to be in that particular `div` (if that particular website is responsive).

```css
.left_side_div {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #f6f8f8;
}

.website_contain_main_div {
  position: relative;
  left: 151px;
}

.website_contain_main_div .website_contain_div {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_side_div"></div>
<div class="website_contain_main_div">
  <div class="website_contain_div">
    <iframe class="no_border" src="http://html.com/tags/iframe/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What to do with `iframe` content? `iframe` size cannot be just fit to content using pure CSS. Responsive `div` is trivial, responsive `iframe` is not.

Comment: there is a customization in website that is loaded in iframe. and that customization will be done in left side div.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution**

```css
  .left_side_div {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #f6f8f8;
 }

.YourIframeClass {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 65.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /*<<--- THIS IS THE KEY*/
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.YourIframeClass iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class='left_side_div'> 
 LEFT DIV
 </div>
<div class='YourIframeClass'>
  <iframe class="no_border" src="http://html.com/tags/iframe/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: i want left div to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using percentage based resolutions.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.left_side_div {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #f6f8f8;
}

.website_contain_main_div {
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/26pj7kmq/)

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox here. Demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  /* become flex-container */
  /* its direct children will be flex items */
  /* by default flex-items stretch to container height */
  display: flex;
}

.left_side_div {
  width: 150px;
}

.website_contain_main_div {
  /* occupy remaining width */
  flex: 1;
}

.website_contain_div {
  height: 100%;
}

.website_contain_div > iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_side_div"></div>
<div class="website_contain_main_div">
  <div class="website_contain_div">
    <iframe class="no_border" src="http://html.com/tags/iframe/"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if possible then can you come on TeamViewer?

Comment: @Rishi No. I can assist you just answering questions here.

Comment: I have applied your solution. but it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Rishi Can you please clarify what exactly is not working?

Comment: in my `website_contain_div` there is iframe and i am loading various website to check if my div is responsive or not to keep all the contents of particular website. I don't get result as my expectaion.

Comment: @Rishi 1) You want your iframe's `height` to fit content? 2) iframe width is OK (100% of screen width - 150px), yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150597/discussion-between-rishi-and-vadim-ovchinnikov).